# Questions while updating some scanner code to use ICU

Tags: c, utf-8, icu

I am working on a rudimentary hand-coded lexical scanner and wish to support UTF-8 input (it's not 1970 anymore!). Input characters are read from `stdin` or a file one at a time and pushed into a buffer until whitespace is seen, etc. I thought about writing my own wrapper for `fgetc()` that would instead return `char[]` of bytes that make up the UTF-8 character and work with the result as a string... it'd be easy enough, but would become a slippery-slope. I'd rather not waste time re-inventing the wheel and instead use an existing, tested library like [ICU](http://icu-project.org/). And so now I have a non-UTF-8 supporting code that works with `fgetc()`, `isspace()`, `strcmp()`, etc. which I am trying to update to use ICU. This is my first foray with ICU and have been reading through the documentation and trying to find usage examples with Google code search, but there are still some points of confusion I'm hoping someone will be able to clarify.

The `u_fgetc()` function returns `UChar`, and `u_fgetcx()` returns `UChar32`... the documentation recommends using `u_fgetcx()` to read codepoints, so that's what I'm starting with. I'm keeping the same approach as above, but I'm pushing `UChar32`s into a buffer instead of `char`s.

- What is the proper way to compare a character against a known value? Originally I was able to do `if (c == '+')` to check if the plus-sign was fetched from the input. GCC doesn't complain when `c` is a `UChar32` (which is then a comparison between `UChar32` and `char`) but is this really proper?
- I was able to use `strcmp()` to compare the buffered characters with a known value, for example `if ((strcmp(buf, "else") == 0)`. There is `u_strcmp()` provided by ICU and I think I may need to use the `U_STRING_DECL` and `U_STRING_INIT` macros to specify the known literal, but I am not certain. The documentation shows they result in `UChar[]`, though I assume I need `UChar32[]`... and I'm uncertain how to use them correctly anyway. Any guidance here would be welcomed.
- After reading in a series of numeric characters I have been converting them with `strtol()` so I can work with them. Is there a similar function made available by ICU since I am converting `UChar32[]` now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UChar` is for holding a *Code Unit*, while `UChar32` is for holding a *Code Point*. If your input stays on the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (BMP), `UChar` is sufficient, and indeed most ICU functions operate on `UChar[]`.

Strongly recommended reading is the [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings), which explains most of the internals and best practices.

- **What is the proper way to compare a Unicode character variable against a known value?**
  A character (or `UChar` or `UChar32`) is just another integer type with a certain width and signedness, and can be compared to other integer types with the usual caveats and restrictions. As for *defining* a character value, C99 (chapter 6.4.3) provides *Universal character names* notation: `\u` followed by four hex digits, or `\U` followed by eight hex digits, specifying the ISO/IEC 10646 "short identifier". The area below 0x00a0 (with exceptions of 0x0024 `'$'`, 0x0040 `'@'`, and 0x0060 (backtick) is reserved (but can be represented by casting a simple character constant to `UChar`). Also reserved is the range from 0xd800 through 0xdfff (for use by UTF-16).
- **How to define Unicode string literals?** `U_STRING_DECL` and `U_STRING_INIT` are indeed what you're looking for. (As written above, ICU mainly operates on `UChar[]`.) If you were using C++ instead of C, [`UNICODE_STRING_SIMPLE`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unistr_8h.html) (optionally followed by `getTerminatedBuffer()` to yield `UChar[]` again) provides a much more comfortable way of defining Unicode string literals.
- **How to convert a Unicode string representing a numerical into that numerical's value?** [`unum_parse()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unum_8h.html#ac658b91fe7e7b8c8e0657008d77db90d) and its brethren in `unum.h` will help you there.

Comment: Great responses, I will just emphasize for other readers: do your comparisons in Unicode, not as char*s. (So don't use "x" or 'x'). Otherwise you could run into codepage issues.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Unicode value for PLUS SIGN is U+002B, and the normal (Latin-1) value for '+' is also 0x2B (053, 43).  What you wrote is safe enough where the code set is based on ASCII or ISO-8859-x.  The C99 standard provides for Unicode (Universal character names) of the forms `\u0123` and `\U00102345` (with 4 and 8 hexadecimal digits), but stipulates that you cannot specify values less than `\u00A0`, such as `\u002B`.  So, I think what you wrote is correct.

   However, you could save yourself future angst by using an `enum` such as

   ```
    enum { PLUS_SIGN = '+' };
   ```

   defined in an appropriate header and used whereever you need a literal plus sign.  That way, if your assumption (and my assumption) is wrong, you have one place to edit - the header.

   I note that the page on [Strings](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings) with ICU suggests that using UTF-32 in an application is unusual.
2. In pure C, you'd probably use `wcscmp(buf, L"else")`, assuming that the `wchar_t` on your system is equivalent to `uint32_t` and/or UChar32.  There seem to be ways to use `UnicodeString` and `UNICODE_STRING("...")` followed by `ToUTF32()` to create a UTF-32 string.  There may also be neater ways.
3. There are 'Formatting' classes which handle both formatting and parsing.  You would probably use classes derived from the [`NumberFormat`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classNumberFormat.html) class.